# wrap divs in container IF they directly follow one another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap two divs in a container BUT only if they directly follow one another.

TRUE

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

FALSE

```
<div class="element"></div>
<p class="different-element"></p>
<div class="element"></div>
```

I know how to wrap them using `.wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>')`

Just wondering how to catch that they follow each other. I was thinking that `.next()` would work and using `if( $('.element').next('.elememt') == true)`
Then if the condition is true wrapping them using `.wrapALL()` - but this doesn't work.

`.has()` won't work as it only checks for descendants.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Ha ha. Nice question. But why? `:)`

Comment: If it's purely presentational, you could use CSS and do something like uh.. .element:nth-child(odd) { border-top: solid 1px red }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the sibling selector; `+`:

```
var $secondElement = $('.element + .element');
$secondElement.add($secondElement.prev()).wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>')
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e74m9jqL/)

Note that you may need more complicated logic if there are more than two `.element` siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to check with `+` sibling selector, which selects the very next element. Extending [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)'s answer:

```
var $secondElement = $('.element + .element');
$secondElement.add($secondElement.prev(".element")).wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>')
```

*Note: I have to change my answer little bit, as already it has been answered in a better way by Rory. I am not deleting because, even I thought the same, as it is a original idea.*

Comment: Note that the selector in `prev()` is redundant as the element itself will *only* be selected if it's previous sibling is a `.element` ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know. I don't have any other choice than ultimately changing by adding some gibberish, to make sure it is not a copy of yours, although we both thought at the same time and you had posted 10 seconds before me, but they are the same answer. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check if the index of next sibling are same

```
 if ( $( ".element" ).next().index() == $( ".element" ).next( ".element" ).index() )
{
  alert( "yes" );
  $( ".element" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" );
}
else
{
  alert( "no" );
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/wwwg03pt/1/)